# Why can't I execute functions based on a radio button selection? Nested functions are not working: undefined or unused

Tags: javascript, html

I am teaching myself JavaScript.
GOAL: I want the radio button to determine which functions to run. I want to group functions so that some specific functions run while others run for the other radio button.

I realize my code is very messy but I am learning and I can't figure out what the issue is.

---

Steps:

1. user picks a game type with the radio buttons - player v player or player v computer
2. user hits submit button
3. a value gets assigned to the game object depending on radio button choice
4. if game = pvp, then run pvp()
5. if game = pvc, then run pvc() (i haven't written this yet because step 4 doesn't even work)

at step 4, I get an error that one of my functions in pvp() is not defined

---

If I remove the outer function pvp(), all of the functions work perfectly.

I am trying to understand why a function of mine is not running when a user picks a radio button. I can't understand why my nested functions come up undefined or unused.

I have moved variables around to see if there is a scope/hoisting issue. I have tried debugging with the console and I can't get anywhere. I set game = "abc" and I want to run functions when game = "abc". I want to run other functions when game = "def".

I have looked into window.onload() and it doesn't apply to my project. I think.

I made sure the script tag is placed at the end of my html.

Code:

```js
'use-strict';

//declare variables here
let boxs = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
let statusTxt = document.querySelector('#status');
let btnRestart = document.querySelector('#restart');
let btnStart = document.querySelector('#start');
let btnNewGame = document.querySelector('#newGame');

//a timer for seconds when the game starts
//example in the text for the window.onload but I don't want to use that
//I need to start this timer when the first token is placed.....

//set up x and o stamps
//fix the height here because stamps are huge in the game
//I need to figure out how to get the players to be randomly started

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//which type of game is being played? test radio buttons...
//run functions based on what the value ofgame is...

btnStart.addEventListener("click", e => {
  console.log(e);
});

btnNewGame.addEventListener("click", e => {
  console.log(e);
});

var game;

//i have a hoisted variable problem
game = "no game radio button";
console.log("test game type at page load = " + game);

function checkGameType() {

  btnPVP = document.getElementById("pvp");
  btnPVC = document.getElementById("pvc");
  btnPVPchecked = document.getElementById("pvp").checked;
  btnPVCchecked = document.getElementById("pvc").checked;

  if (document.getElementById("pvp").checked) {
    document.getElementById("messageGame").innerHTML = "Player V Player Game!";
    console.log("player v player");
    clearCount();
    count = 0;
    game = "pvp";
    console.log("test game type at page load = " + game);

  } else if (document.getElementById("pvc").checked) {
    document.getElementById("messageGame").innerHTML = "Player V Computer Game!";
    console.log("player v computer");
    game = "pvc";
    console.log("test game type at page load = " + game);

  } else if (!btnPVPchecked && !btnPVCchecked) {
    document.getElementById("messageGame").innerHTML = "No Game Selected!";
    console.log("no game type selcted");
    game = "none";
    console.log("test game type at page load = " + game);
  }
} //end checkGameType

function clearGameType() {

  btnPVPunchecked = (document.getElementById("pvp").checked = false);
  btnPVCunchecked = !(document.getElementById("pvc").checked = false);
  console.log("game selection has been cleared");
  document.getElementById("messageGame").innerHTML = "Pick a game!";
  restartGame();
  game = "none";
  console.log(game + " ---- New Game var test");

} //end clearGameType

function restartGame() {
  options = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];

  setRandomPlayer();

  running = true;
  statusTxt.textContent = 'New Game! ' + player + ' turn!';

  boxs.forEach(box => {
    box.innerHTML = "";
    box.classList.remove('win');
  });
  counter = 0;
  stopCount();
} //end of restartgame

///////////////////////////////
//set up timer here so it can be accessed in funcs
//function for game type player v player
//game timer that looks ugly but works

//i tried making this a nested function and it was a disaster
var counter = 0;
var timeout;
var timer_on = 0;

function timedCount() {
  document.getElementById("timeClock").innerHTML = counter + " seconds";
  counter++;
  timeout = setTimeout(timedCount, 1000);
  //testing the timer in console
  //console.log(counter);
}

function startCount() {
  if (!timer_on) {
    timer_on = 1;
    timedCount();
  }
  //console.log(counter);
}

function stopCount() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timer_on = 0;
  //counter = 0;
  document.getElementById("timeClock").innerHTML = counter + " seconds";
}

function clearCount() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  counter = 0;
}

//let currentPlayer=x; -- this is for if I wanted to start as x stamp every time

//initialize empty box options for the game board here

//when the game first loads in the browser

function init() {
  //the game waits for user interaction - a click in the box
  boxs.forEach(box => box.addEventListener('click', boxClick));
  btnRestart.addEventListener('click', restartGame);
  setRandomPlayer();
  statusTxt.textContent = 'Current Game - player ' + player + ' ----- turn!';
  running = true;
  console.log(game + " test in init");
  //here i see that game is undefined so this is why my pvp func is not working below....

} //end of init

init();

function setRandomPlayer() {
  //wow it actually works, sometimes o starts, sometimes x starts
  currentPlayer = Math.random() > 0.5 ? x : o; //images are being used not x and o
  //this needs to be fixed because it doesn't match the random player order
  //ok fixed the status message matches the current player
  player = currentPlayer;
} //end of random player func

function pvp() {

  var x = "x";
  var o = "o";
  var options = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
  var running = false;

  //combo of wins possible that game checks for after each turn
  var win = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
  ];

  console.log('before game play func ---- ' + game);

  ///////////////////////////////
  //start game play here
  function boxClick() {
    const index = this.dataset.index;
    //if
    if (options[index] !== "" || !running) {
      return;
    }
    console.log("a click is recorded here");
    updateBox(this, index);
    isWinner();
  }

  //use a button to start the game play and attach timer to that     
  //not needed ^; timer works fine onclick, finally

  function updateBox(box, index) {
    options[index] = player;
    //dynamic html in the doc
    box.innerHTML = currentPlayer;
    console.log(currentPlayer + " plays their turn");
  }

  function nextPlayer() {
    player = (player === "x") ? "o" : "x";
    currentPlayer = (currentPlayer === x) ? o : x;
    statusTxt.textContent = player + ' turn';
    console.log("next player's turn " + currentPlayer);
  }

  //did anyone win
  function isWinner() {
    let isWon = false;

    for (let i = 0; i < win.length; i++) {
      const condition = win[i]; //[0,1,2]
      const box1 = options[condition[0]];
      const box2 = options[condition[1]];
      const box3 = options[condition[2]];
      if (box1 === "" || box2 === "" || box3 === "") {
        continue;
      }
      if (box1 === box2 && box2 === box3) {
        isWon = true;
        boxs[condition[0]].classList.add('win');
        boxs[condition[1]].classList.add('win');
        boxs[condition[2]].classList.add('win');
      }
    }

    if (isWon) {
      statusTxt.textContent = 'player ' + player + ' wins!!';
      running = false;
      //stop the timer here too
      stopCount();

    } else if (!options.includes("")) {
      statusTxt.textContent = 'The Game is Tied';
      running = false;
    } else {
      nextPlayer();
    }
  } //end of check winner
  //
} //end of pvp game


//functionality for game type player v computer
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
</head>

<body>


  <br>
  <h3>What kind of game do you want to play ?</h3><br>

  <input type="radio" id="pvp" name="gameType" value="Player v Player">Player v Player
  <input type="radio" id="pvc" name="gameType" value="Player v Computer" />Player v Computer<br><br>
  <button id="start" onclick="checkGameType()">START!</button>
  <button id="newGame" onclick="clearGameType()">New Game</button>

  <div id="messageGame"></div><br>
  <div>----[[Game Clock]]----</div>
  <p id="timeClock"> </p>
  <div id="status">Place your stamp to start playing!</div>

  <div class="container" id="board">
    <div data-index="0" class="box" onclick="startCount()"></div>
    <div data-index="1" class="box" onclick="startCount()"></div>
    <div data-index="2" class="box" onclick="startCount()"></div>
    <div data-index="3" class="box" onclick="startCount()"></div>
    <div data-index="4" class="box" onclick="startCount()"></div>
    <div data-index="5" class="box" onclick="startCount()"></div>
    <div data-index="6" class="box" onclick="startCount()"></div>
    <div data-index="7" class="box" onclick="startCount()"></div>
    <div data-index="8" class="box" onclick="startCount()"></div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button id="restart" onclick="restartGame()">Restart</button>

  <script src="pvpgame.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `I want to group functions so that some specific functions run while others run for the other radio button.` Use specific class names in the elements you want to run a certain function with, then iterate over those nodes and add the corresponding eventListsner call back function to those nodeLists

Comment: You need to learn to declare all your local variables properly. And it's 2023, use `let` and `const`, not `var`.

Comment: `boxClick()` is nested inside `pvp()`, so you can't reference it from the `init()` function. Does it really need to be a local function?

Comment: Where is your `if (game == "pvp") { pvp(); }` code?

Comment: I suspect what you really should be using is classes. Define a base class for all games, and then subclasses `PvP` and `PvC` for the different game types.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for your feedback. I looked up the definitions of let, var, and const again to make sure i understand when to use them. I have updated my variables where appropriate and I don't use var anymore.

Also, I didn't think about using a conditional and then calling the pvp() function within it. I tried it out. I tested the value of "game" with console.log, and the conditional worked correctly.

Thanks for pointing out boxClick()'s location. That was causing the problem with undefined function.

Comment: @dalelandry thank you for the class idea. I have added classes to the radio elements. I am working on the eventListeners for them.

Comment: See my posted example answer and let me know if something is not working for you or not clear...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) with an [eventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and the [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) to get the value of the radio button that is pressed. For your instance if you want to know who to place as an opponent for the user when they click the radio button that asks **player** or **computer** as an *opponent*, you query the elements, then iterate over them and run the nodes in the [nodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) through an **eventListener**. Once the user inputs, check the **value** of the radio button and then use logic in the callback function to handle what you wish to do from there.

EDIT: I realized a bit more poignant answer would be better for your case... See my edit please. In the edit I have included a start button as you have in your example to first see if they are ready to start the game, once `start` is pressed we check which radio button is checked, if one is not checked we run the `err()` function and let user know to select an opponent `'input[name="opponent"]:checked'`, once they select an opponent and there is indeed a radio button pressed, you can then use more logic to see which player was chosen and then run logic for that specific choice.

Very simple example below but hopefully you get the gist.

```js
const startGameBtn = document.querySelector('#start-game');
const board = document.querySelector('#board');

const playGame = (str) => {
  let challenge;
  if(str === 'computer'){
    // run code here for when you play against the computer...
    challenger = `the whiley ${str}`;
  }
  if(str === 'player'){
    // run code here for when you play against another player...
    challenger = `another ${str}`;
  }
  board.innerHTML = `<span class="${str}">You have decided to play against ${challenger}...</span>`;
}

const err = (el) => {
  el.innerHTML = `<span class="err">Please choose an opponent above before starting the game!</span>`;
}

const startGame = (e) => {
  const opponent = document.querySelector('input[name="opponent"]:checked');
  if(opponent) {
    playGame(opponent.value);
    // further conditional or method to handle which player is chosen.
  } else {
    err(board);
  }    
}

startGameBtn.addEventListener('click', startGame);
```

```css
#board {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.err {
  color: darkred;
  background-color: pink;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.player {
  color: skyblue;
  background-color: darkblue;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.computer {
  color: darkorange;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="game-board">
  <div>Would you like to play against a player? <input type="radio" name="opponent" value="player" class="opponent"></div>

  <div>Would you like to play against the computer? <input type="radio" name="opponent" value="computer" class="opponent"></div>

  <button id="start-game">Start</button>

  <div id="board"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for showing me a structure to separate the game play and then call the right functions for each